# Total uptime of a spark application greater than cumulative time of all spark job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am executing below pyspark code in AWS EMR cluster.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
print("Program Start")
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("My App").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([('ABC','abc',7),('DEF' , 'def', 8),('XYZ','xyz',9)],['first_name','last_name', 'age'])
df.printSchema()
df.show()
print("Program End")
```

Below is the DAG representation
[image: Spark DAG]

Total job uptime is 13seconds but total duration of job id 0 and 1 is 6 sec and 97 ms. So **what is spark doing during this extra time of  ~7 seconds.** Event timeline is also showing no activity for this ~7seconds.